# add module omfwd and omkafka to rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog, rsyslogd, kafka

I install `rsyslog` latest version, but without `omfwd` and `omkafka` module! how can I add these modules?
thanks.

Comment: What system are you using? Eg, on fedora `omfwd` is a builtin so you dont load it. and `omkafka` is in a separate rpm package that you need to install.

Comment: @meuh rsyslog version : `8.1910.0`, os: `centos 7`. I can't find `rpm` for this version rsyslog! You have a link download please?

Comment: I don't know anything about centos, but there seems to be an rpm *rsyslog-kafka* on [centos.org update repository](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/x86_64/Packages/)

Comment: ... so, have you tried `yum install rsyslog-kafka`?